# Free Resource For Windows Scripting

Tags: windows-server-2003, scripting

I have to automate several tasks on a windows 2003 server machine. I have been struggling with all sorts of quirks in windows batch files (like the lack of SLEEP command and the fact that WMIC is not PSEXEC friendly...). Is there a free resource out there that can act as a reference for windows scripting? The documentation I found on Microsoft are not adequate, they describe each function/keyword in detail but they don't have (or at least I could not find) anything on creating complex scripts.

Comment: What kind of scripting? vbscript? powershell?

Comment: Actually I was doing vanilla batch files but powershell definitely seems like the way to go, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [technet scriptcenter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/default.aspx) is a one stop shop for all things related to microsoft scripting.  There are various tutorials and hours of introductory video and labs.

Answer (score 1):

Scriptcenter is good.  Another resource is MVPS.org's [scripting site](http://www.mvps.org/scripting/).

Answer (score 1):

[**Powershell.com**](http://powershell.com) is a great resource for Powershell scripting.  Also, have a look a this free e-book on the site - [**Mastering Powershell**](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/) by Dr. Tobias Weltner.  Good stuff.